# How to authenticate BigQuery in R on Linux Server (bigrquery)

Tags: r, linux, authentication, google-bigquery, bigrquery

We are trying to authenticate to BigQuery in an R script scheduled to run on a linux server. We have:

```
bigrquery::bq_auth(path = '~/path-to/credentials/our-creds.json')
```

and when I run this locally in R, I get this prompt

```
The bigrquery package is requesting access to your Google account.
Select a pre-authorised account or enter '0' to obtain a new token.
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to cancel.

1: myemail@gmail.com

Selection:
```

When we run this on our linux server via `Rscript our_script.R`, we get the following error:

```
Error: Can't get Google credentials.
Are you running bigrquery in a non-interactive session? Consider:
  * Call `bq_auth()` directly with all necessary specifics.
Execution halted
```

When we run this on our linux server via `R` to open up R, and then manually running the line of code, we get:

```
> bigrquery::bq_auth(path = '~/path-to/credentials/our-creds.json')
Waiting for authentication in browser...
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
```

and because we don't have a browser to authenticate in (we are SSH'd into our linux server which lives on GCP), the terminal hangs here...

How can we successfully authenticate on the server, so `Rscript out_script.R` can run successfully?

**Edit:** Info on our server:

[image]

let me know if I can share additional info to help with this. Also we tried adding `myemail@gmail.com` to bigrquery's `email` parameter, but this did not resolve the issue. I see there is a `token` parameter and perhaps we can manually add a token in somewhere? This is all super frustrating because I thought using the service account key was supposed to resolve this issue, and yet we are pointing to a valid service account key with bigquery permissions, and yet still cannot authenticate on the server.

Comment: What is the R version that you have installed? I executed a [sample script](https://gist.github.com/kabilanmohanraj/fd2b5a54ff22c4527ff8f155dc46e8f6) with R version 3.5.2 and was able to successfully query tables in BigQuery. I got the error `Can't get Google credentials` when the path to the service account key was not correctly passed to the `bq_auth()` function.

Comment: So, please consider checking the service account key path on the Linux server. If that doesn’t help, update all the R packages installed on your Linux server using the command `update.packages(ask=FALSE)` after running `sudo R` to invoke the interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same [question](https://community.rstudio.com/t/bq-auth-to-authenticate-bigrquery-using-service-account-on-a-linux-server/118077) was asked in the RStudio community forum. Posting the [discussion](https://community.rstudio.com/t/bq-auth-to-authenticate-bigrquery-using-service-account-on-a-linux-server/118077/2) here for posterity.

> A few troubleshooting ideas:
>
> > ... R script scheduled to run on a linux server....
>
> Whenever I hear "scheduled", I think "cron" and when I hear "cron", I
> think "path problems". So in the server / schedule context, I
> recommend doing very pedantic checks that you truly understand what
> working directory is, who the user is, and whether a path is resolving
> to what you intend.
>
> However, the fact that this service account token doesn't even seem to
> work for you in a local interactive session suggests something is
> wrong with the file. Historically, people have tried to use other JSON
> files, such as the JSON for an OAuth client, as if it were the JSON
> for a service account, which does not work, for obvious reasons.
>
> You can gain more insight into how this is failing and falling through
> to interactive auth by using the gargle verbosity option as described
> here:
>
> > gargle.r-lib.org - [Troubleshooting gargle auth](https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/troubleshooting.html) - gargle
>
> And in case you have not already found it (and for the benefit of
> other readers) here is a general overview of how to set up
> non-interactive auth:
>
> > gargle.r-lib.org - [Non-interactive auth](https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/non-interactive-auth.html) - gargle

As acknowledged by @Canovice in the same forum [thread](https://community.rstudio.com/t/bq-auth-to-authenticate-bigrquery-using-service-account-on-a-linux-server/118077/4), the issue was due to a faulty service account key used in the `bq_auth()` function.